# SSRS Reporting services subscriptions not sending email to client or sending duplicates

Tags: reporting-services

**Senario 1 :**

I am sending different clients same report with different data. For Example Client 1 wants reports for xyz region and Client 2 requires for other region.

I have created subscription for report once and then pick subscription Id and ScheduleId from Report server table to manually trigger

I am retrieving all setups from database for clients defined email address and regions. Looping through cursor I am processing those details and updating Email Address and Report Parameters in the `[ReportServer].[dbo].[Susbcriptions]`

Then using below SQL send PDF to the clients.

```
exec ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='SharedSchedule', @EventData=@ScheduleID

WaitFor Delay 00:00:45 - To allow report processiong to be finished.
```

Problem1: When Looping through cursor - sometimes client 2 never gets report.

**Senario2:**

For Example, I want to send different license details License 1, License 2 and License 3 to the one client.
Using above method sometimes clients gets License 1 details report 2 times and then License2 details report skipped.

Hope this will provide more information. I am using **SQL SERver 2008 Reporting services**.

Answer (score 0):

What goes on internally for SSRS subscriptions is a bit complicated. (See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22163743/201021).

An alternative to rolling your own solution would be to use Data Driven Subscriptions which is a feature of SSRS in SQL Server 2005 and up. There is a good MSDN article on how to use them: [Create a Data-Driven Subscription (SSRS Tutorial)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx)

If that won't work for you I'd recommend using the web service rather than trying to do this directly in the SSRS database. This will ensure that SSRS still has control over exactly how the subscriptions are run. Plus the structure of the Report Server database isn't guaranteed, while the web service should remain relatively the same. A few good resources:

- [MSDN Report Server Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx)
- [MSDN Accessing the (SSRS) SOAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx)
- [Codeproject article: Programmatically Playing With SSRS Subscriptions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions)